# What is the difference between VOR(D), VOR(V) and VOR(S) seen in the table?

Tags: vor, location-identifiers

What is the difference between **VOR(D)**, **VOR(V)** and **VOR(S)** seen in the table? What do the letters **D**, **V** and **S** stand for or represent?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those letters are different [ARINC 424](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARINC_424) Route Type identifiers for instrument approaches:

> **5.7 Route Type (RT TYPE)**
>
> Definition/Description: The “Route Type” field defines
> the type of Enroute Airway, Preferred Route, Airport and
> Heliport SID/STAR/Approach Routes of which the record
> is an element. [...]
>
> Source/Content: The content of this field (for approach
> procedures) will be as indicated in the following tables: [...]
>
> | Approach Route Type Description | Route Type Field Content |
> | --- | --- |
> | Approach Transition | A |
> | Localizer/Backcourse Approach | B |
> | **VORDME Approach** | **D** |
> | Flight Management System (FMS) Approach | F |
> | Instrument Guidance System (IGS) Approach | G |
> | Instrument Landing System (ILS) Approach | I |
> | GNSS Landing System (GLS) Approach | J |
> | Localizer Only (LOC) Approach | L |
> | Microwave Landing System (MLS) Approach | M |
> | Non-Directional Beacon (NDB) Approach | N |
> | Global Positioning System (GPS) Approach | P |
> | Non-Directional Beacon + DME (NDB+DME) Approach | Q |
> | Area Navigation (RNAV) Approach | R |
> | **VOR Approach using VORDME/VORTAC** | **S** |
> | TACAN Approach | T |
> | Simplified Directional Facility (SDF) Approach | U |
> | **VOR Approach** | **V** |
> | Microwave Landing System (MLS), Type A Approach | W |
> | Localizer Directional Aid (LDA) Approach | X |
> | Microwave Landing System (MLS), Type B and C Approach | Y |
> | Missed Approach | Z |

<sup>(ARINC 424 - 5.0 NAVIGATION DATA - FIELD DEFINITIONS)</sup>

So in your case, the **V** is a VOR approach without DME, the **D** includes DME and the **S** is for combined VOR/DME and TACAN (VORTAC).

Similarly, the ILS **I**, **L** and **B** correspond to regular ILS, localizer and backcourse approaches respectively.